# C# DbContext EF use config variable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, configuration

I am trying to retrieve a connection string from app settings.  Below is the code from the program.cs.

```
   {
       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
       }

       public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
           Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .ConfigureLogging(builder => builder.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics())
               .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
               {
                   webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
               });
   }
```

I want to replace the connection string with a value retrieved from app settings in my ef context class derived from dbcontext.

```
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=xxx;Database=xxx;User Id=xxx;Password=xxx");
            }
```

I am not sure how to do so using dependency injection and can't use this approach because there is no definition for appsettings from Configuration manager https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your efforts @T McKeown.

It turns there was some unnecessary code in the context class with a hard coded connection string.  (see original post)

It is actually coded correctly in my startup.cs
[image]

It really helps me to type out the the issue and try different things though - so thanks for your efforts and time.